# .net 4.0 winforms, easy way to get text controls to remember previous input?

Tags: .net

I want my text box controls to remember previous input and have intellisense, like web control inputs.

Is there a quick, free and easy to implement solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's one way of doing it using a mixture of listboxes and textboxes](http://mydotnet.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/intellisense-in-a-windows-forms-textbox/). I quite like this solution actaully.